# Permission page broken

Tags: 7, theming

[image]

All other pages are being loaded fine but when I go to permissions page it comes like this. What may be the reason for this ? Please help.

Comment: I tried in different browsers and also cleared the cache. Still getting the page like that.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem few days ago.
Do you have the **devel module** install?

For me it was the problem, i can't explain why but when i desintalled it, all worked fine.

So maybe, try to desactivate and unistall it and maybe your page permission will work again.

PS: *i just re-install the devel module to make a test and i have exatly the same permission page than you. For me it's the devel module the problem. (I'm new in Drupal so i had certainly make a mistake somewhere)*

Comment: Oh you are right. Uninstalling devel module solved the problem for now :). But we should also look for the permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be a PHP Memory Limit issue. Is this only happening on your local / dev or also on your remote server?

Comment: I have not uploaded to remote server yet.Still developing. If PHP memory is issue , how to solve it ?

Comment: Run a phpinfo() (or use the devel module /devel/phpinfo) to see how much memory you have. Its the memory_limit value. TO increase, you need to set another value in the php.ini or ask your hoster.

Comment: @Lance- I increased the memory limit from 128 to 256 in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini . But still showing the problem when I install devel module. Any other reasons for this problem that you know ? Is the php.ini file that I edited was correct or I should get the file somewhere else ? I need to solve the problem permanently. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem noted above, but after checking my modules, I do not have devel installed.  Are there any other solutions to this issue out there?

Answer (score -2):

May be the permission listing makes the memory problem.You have to update the permission listing page to a simple one.

Try the [Filter permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/filter_perms)

Comment: How would this module help, exactly?

Comment: There may be lots of user roles within the app. While loading all the permission together may cause the page break..

Comment: This module will let you select each role with many types. All to All is also possible too

Comment: Please edit your answer to provide details. Comments are for more "side" tasks, like asking for claifications ot notifying they were made.